# Prove $a^n$ is not convergent for $a>1$

Tags: real-analysis

We have to prove that $a^n$ is not convergent if $a>1$. I tried approaching this problem by trying to prove that it is not bounded, hence not convergent. Also it seems obvious that $a^n$ is increasing with increase in power. But I am not able to prove this. Please help.

Comment: Your guess is correct - what have you tried?

Comment: Write $a=1+b$ with $b>0$. Can you use the binomial formula to show that $a^n\ge 1+nb$?

Comment: It it were convergent, say to some limit $L$, then $a^{n+1}$ would be convergent to the same limit $L$. As $a^{n+1} = a\cdot a^{n}$, taking limits on both sides gives $L = aL$, whence $L(a-1) = 0$. Since $a \neq 1$, this forces $L = 0$. But that's absurd since $a^n$ is positive and increasing. (Proof that $a^n$ is increasing is easy: multiply both sides of $a > 1$ by $a^{n}$ to conclude $a^{n+1} > a^n$.)